# Import posts with featured images

Tags: export

I am trying to make an import of posts from my old blog installation.

It works fine for posts content but fails for featured images.

I've done: tools -> export -> posts -> selected a category.

In the xml i can see the fields of the featured images with the old path...but in the back-end i can't see any featured image uploaded...

Is there something i am missing?

Comment: Please search inside [tag:migration]. The question has been answered multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If you export a single post type (i.e. posts, pages, a custom post type, etc...) it will not include attached media files like featured images.  That's incredibly idiotic, to me, but your options are --

- Export everything from site (which will include featured images), then modify the XML file as needed before importing to the new site
- Use a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/export-featured-images/)
- [Suggest and provide feedback](https://wordpress.org/support/forum/requests-and-feedback)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a single step process that does this, but I did find a two step approach that accomplishes it. See my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/337230/66368) for further instructions.

Good luck!